# Is it possible to extract the prescribed boundary condition and its nodal coordinates in Ansys Mechanical?

Tags: ansys

Let's say I have 3 boundary conditions and I want to extract the nodal coordinates and the boundary condition value for each boundary condition separately.
I tried Ipython scripting and pyAnsys but it exports the whole mesh. I would be very happy if I could extract at least the nodal coordinates at each boundary condition.

Please, note that I am talking about the mesh only i.e. I don't want the deformed nodal coordinates.

Comment: Why don't you try in APDL instead of python?

Comment: sorry, How do I access APDL from Ansys Mechanical?

Comment: At the top of the window there is a command bar, where you can type your commands